# AUDI A4 2009 1.8 TFSI engine compatibility (swapping engines)

Tags: engine, audi, a4

I have a 2009 A4 1.8 TFSI Basically, I need a new engine. On searching I have been told a CABA Engine will fit even though my engine is CDHA. I have been offered two CABA engines but can't find any CDHA engines so am now wondering if I can just replace with one of CABA engines?? Any help/advise would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The only information that actually describes the changes technically is in this VW study material:

http://www.vaglinks.com/vaglinks_com/Docs/SSP/VWUSA.COM_SSP_436_2.0L_TFSI.pdf

[image]

This information tells me the CDHA engine supercedes the CABA engine and has changes to:

- Bearing diameter reduced
- Modified piston
- Modified piston rings
- Different honing process
- Changed vacuum pump.

It will definitely be compatible, assuming the whole engine is swapped, but what those changes were made to the engine design for, I cannot tell you.